# Android Presentation display

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean

I've read about Presentation display support in 4.2.2, but I cannot understand - Presentation supports only WiDi-display or HDMI too?

**EDIT** I want to build application which uses external monitor to display some media (video, photos or gallery) and built-in display as a control panel (only button and some settings)

Comment: check out this [article](http://www.androidpolice.com/2012/11/16/so-what-is-this-miracast-thing-and-how-does-it-work-anyway/)

Comment: Yeah, look like answer. But is also looks like this feature isn't very popular :(

Comment: Like the article said, it seems like it is one of the features that Google has announced, but hasn't really put enough time into in order to make it really useful. Maybe in future releases they will add more functionality.

Comment: THe may problem is following: vendors don't implement this feature in them firmwares, and it is sad, because currently I really need it

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If you give more detail in your question, then people can give you more helpful answers.

Comment: See edit please